# SQL select query not limiting to only one element in nodeJS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, select

I'm struggling to select the ID of the last record in DB and alert it after insert. I have wrote and I have found that the best solution is to select descending with `LIMIT` . The query is fine, it works, but it selects each rows from last to the first, not only the last and I can't figure out why. Thanks !

```
app.post('/alert', function(req,res) {

    var query = "SELECT id FROM Control ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);

    });
});
```

Comment: but you're returning one row, that is correct, what's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that in console.log(result), it shows the id of the last row to infinity. I mean, it should show id once, and that's all. But it shows `[ { id: 704 } ]
[ { id: 704 } ]
[ { id: 704 } ]
[ { id: 704 } ]
` .. and it still goes if I don't stop it. And because of that, the alert is not getting the data correctly.

Comment: does it happen with all queries?

Comment: No. I have an insert and another select, which works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MAX:

```
app.post('/alert', function(req,res) {

var query = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM Control";
connection.query(query, function(error, result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);

});
});
```

Comment: Still the same thing. Why is it goint to infinity with the select?

Comment: Is the query called multiple times?

Comment: Only once in the click method of a button, after the insert which works compltely fine

Comment: Solved. The problem was that my function in jquery was called alert, and it was a confusion beetwen my function call and other alerts I had. Thanks a lot !